# Как сохранить SSH у VPS при включенном VPN

Tags: сеть, vps, vpn, iptables, openvpn

Не получается получить доступ к vps при вклеченном на нем openvpn клиенте.
Собственно, задача, чтобы vps был частью частной сети VPN и я мог к нему подключиться удаленно через ssh по его публичному адресу.

**Как я настраивал окружение:**

Создал vps и настроил на нем OpenVPN сервер.
**Доступ:**

```
root@185.159.130.117
b7pcJ*NRNnGS
```

Есть удаленный сервер, который я хочу подключить, как клиента Open VPN сети.
**Доступ:**

```
root@45.141.79.89
b7pcJ*NRNnGS
```

Вот так я поднял openVPN сервер (использовал скрипт):

```bash
wget https://git.io/vpn -O openvpn-install.sh
sudo chmod +x openvpn-install.sh
sudo bash openvpn-install.sh
```

А вот код для поднятия клиента:

```bash
sudo apt install apt-transport-https
sudo wget https://swupdate.openvpn.net/repos/openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
sudo apt-key add openvpn-repo-pkg-key.pub
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos/openvpn3-jammy.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openvpn3
openvpn3 session-start --config client1.ovpn
```

(Сертификаты можете взять по пути ~/certs)

Далее на сервере запущен openVPN:

```bash
systemctl start openvpn@server
```

**Подключение проверил - все работает**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uV29h.png

На клиенте при подключении к серверу я сразу теряю ssh.
Задача, чтобы vps был в той же сети VPN, но я мог к нему подключиться по его публичному ip по ssh.

Comment: Более подробно про "я сразу теряю ssh"?

Comment: Как я понимаю, после включения VPN публичный адрес более не доступен для подключения, поэтому соединение обрывается. Вот мне кажется, что нужно настроить разделение на ssh и весь другой трафик, который уже пойдет через VPN

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы коннектитесь к VPS в Linux? Что пишет `route -n` до и после подключения VPS?

Comment: После подключения к VPN я не имею больше доступа к VPS, потому что мой ssh сбрасывается. 
В этом и проблема.

Comment: ваш сервер `root@45.141.79.89` недоступен для экспериментов. Я проверил свой ответ на своём VPS. Проверьте, пожалуйста, у себя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Короткий ответ**

После подключения VPN весь трафик перенаправляется в виртуальный интерфейс, поэтому соединение разрывается. Нужно прописать фиксированное правило маршрутизации, которое сохранит маршрут между вашим рабочим компьютером и VPS.

**Развёрнутый ответ**

Я буду демонстрировать на примере моего VPS сервера `146.71.77.201`.

Для того, чтобы соединение с сервером-клиентом `45.141.79.89` (в моём случае `146.71.77.201`) не разрывалось, нужно настроить на сервере-клиенте маршрут к вашему рабочему компьютеру

1. `ip route list match 0.0.0.0/1` напечатает информацию о дефолтной маршрутизации. У меня это `default via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0 onlink` - гейтвей `146.71.77.1`, сетевая карта `eth0`
2. Теперь узнаем, с какого адреса вы подключились. Это можно сделать несколькими способами, я воспользовался `netstat`:

   ```
   netstat -npt | grep :22
   tcp        0     36 146.71.77.201:22        118.128.28.53:64597     ESTABLISHED 3277529/sshd: root@
   ```

   Вывод команды означает, что к порту SSHD моего VPS сервера есть подключение с адреса `118.128.28.53` (это внешний адрес нашего офисного роутера)
3. Теперь добавим фиксированный маршрут до офисного роутера

   ```
   ip route add 118.128.28.53 via 146.71.77.1
   ```

   (напомню, что 146.71.77.1 - это адрес дефолного гейтвея в локальной сети провайдера). То есть все пакеты в адрес моего офисного роутера пойдут напрямую через `eth0` в обход VPN.
4. Проверяем: `openvpn start-session --config tmp/test.ovpn`

   **SSH подключение к серверу-клиенту на месте ;)**

   `ip route` - смотрим таблицу маршрутизации после подключения VPN:

   ```
   0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
   default via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0 onlink
   10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.1
   10.8.0.0/16 dev tun1 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.0.5
   118.128.28.53 via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0
   128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0
   146.71.77.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 146.71.77.201
   185.159.130.117 via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0
   ```

   Что видим:

   - `0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.0.1 dev tun0` Весь трафик по умолчанию идёт через виртуальный интерфейс `tun0`
   - `185.159.130.117 via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0` Трафик к VPN серверу `185.159.130.117` идёт через локальную сеть провайдера в обход `tun0` (это логично, иначе трафик бы зациклился :) )
   - `118.128.28.53 via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0` Трафик к моему офисному компьютеру идёт через локальную сеть провайдера в обход `tun0`. Благодаря этой строке сохранилось ssh подключение к клиентской машине.

Доказательство - ssh сессия, в которой была запущена сессия VPN, активна после запуска VPN
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Все отлично работает.
А если я подключаюсь с компьютера, который к этой же сети подключен?
Какое правило тогда нужно прописать?

То есть все подключается и работает ровно до того момента, пока я не включаю VPN клиент на том же компьютере, от которого с SSH подключаюсь

Comment: @EgorKozelskij правило для добавления подсети выглядит так `ip route  add 118.128.28.0/24 via 146.71.77.1 dev eth0`. Здесь добавляется сеть с 24-битной маской, то есть все адреса, начинающиеся с `118.128.28`.

Comment: @EgorKozelskij вот тут я не понял. Что означает *все подключается и работает ровно до того момента, пока я не включаю VPN клиент на том же компьютере, от которого с SSH подключаюсь*? сколько у вас компьютеров? Я знаю про два, с адресами 185.159.130.117 и 45.141.79.89, и догадываюсь, что есть ещё рабочий компьютер. О каких ещё идёт речь?

Comment: 1) Компьютер-Сервер (на нем стоит OpenVPN сервер)
2) VPS - с него я подключился к компьютеру-серверу (его адрес 10.8.0.6 внутри сети)
3) Мой рабочий компьютер с внутренним адресом 10.8.0.7 (с него ssh больше не пропадает, если я подключают без включенного VPN). Задача, чтобы компьютеры 2 и 3 видели друг друга по внутренним адресам и компьютер 3 мог с публичного в внутреннего адреса подключаться по SSH  к компьютеру 2

Comment: @EgorKozelskij тут бы нам перейти в чат, но пока я не вижу такую опцию. Поэтому предлагаю вам задать ещё один вопрос и привести в нём детали об адресах компьютеров и для каждого из них указать вывод команды `ip route list`. Плюс внешний сетевой адрес вашей офисной сети. Без таких деталей я затрудняюсь с ответом.